# Rubymine using generator from rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, console, rubymine

I am currently using Rubymine for ruby on rails development. 
After enjoying the console for testing purposes, I want to use the console instead of the build-in Rails Generator for creating new models and such.

But I can't figure out how to use the rails console (Tools | Run Rails Console) for generating -lets say- a new model "user".

```
rails generate model user name:string
```

gives me

> NameError: undefined local variable or method `string' for main:Object

I think I'm just missing something very basic here but I couldn't come up with a solution by myself after several tries :/
I hope you can help me out.

Greets

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you feel that you really must use the console to do this, you have a few options to get to the system.

You can use backticks.

**or**

You can use system()

Your command would then look like `system("rails generate model user name:string")` or it would look like `` `rails generate model user name:string` ``

Comment: Thanks, using the cmd as an external tool in rubymine is working but I can't use the up/down keys like normally working with the cmd... little downside there.

Answer (score 2):

The command you are trying to run is not something that should be run from a ruby console. It is a bash command. The error you are getting is because you are trying to run something that is not ruby in a ruby environment.

Comment: Hm okay, is there any proper command for this to use in the ruby environment?

Comment: Just for fun: `> puts \`rails generate model user name:string\``.  It does "work"...

Comment: Technically Gabe is right but there isn't a good reason to try and force this into the rails console.